# Node.js + socket.io app not working in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, node.js, socket.io, mobile-safari

I have an issue with node js + socket io  which are not working with iphone safari browser and chrome browser. It's working with desktop browsers as well with android phone browsers.

In http case it working well with iphone browsers. The only issue with https case that not working with iphone. Here is my code

app.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/cert.pem')
};
var serverPort = 3008;

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io-client')(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/node_test/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
//  console.log('new connection');

setInterval(function(){

var timeout = new Date().getTime();
  socket.emit('message', timeout);
});

},1000);

server.listen(serverPort, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at %s port', serverPort);
});
```

index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var URL_SERVER = 'https://www.example.com:3008';
  var socket = io.connect(URL_SERVER);
  socket.on('message', function(data) {
jQuery('#show_time').html(data); 
      });
    </script>
<div id="show_time">time....</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No but when debug code. alert not working inside socket.on function. socket.on('message', function(data) { alert('test')

Comment: Is the connection getting established properly? I mean is your `io.on('connection', function(socket) {....});`
getting executed?

Comment: Yes and it's working with other desktop and android browsers. Only issue with iphone browsers. socket.io not working with ios browser. I have also checked in ipad same issue there.

Comment: Please check out [this](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/websockets-and-sockets-io/) link. It might be useful for you.

Comment: Finally lot of research over net and looking different forum i have resolved this issue. I have added cert bundle file(ca.crt) with key and cert. Thanks all for your support.

Comment: I've rollback your replacement of the question by a solution. Please find your solution in the revision history and post it as an answer of its own.