# Angular 6 App Wont Load on mobile browser (iPhone) or safari

Tags: angular, heroku, progressive-web-apps

I deployed an Angular 6 PWA with Firebase through Heroku.

On my desktop (windows) and Mac laptop the site displays and works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

https://supportchatdev.herokuapp.com

On mobile browsers on my iPhone and safari on my mac, the site wont load at all.

On my Mac through the safari dev tools, in the sources, I get two or three files that seem to be infinitely loading.

I am not sure which files of mine would be useful to post for purposes of debugging the issue, so whatever someone wants to see I can post. I just do not want to post random files that are irrelevant.

Thanks!

*********EDIT************
Here is a screenshot of the loading on safari. It just sites here and never does anything
[Safari loading in dev console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/accmp.jpg)

After more research, this seems to be the same issue I am having, though I am having a hard time understanding how to add the cert file to my app:

[Node.js + socket.io app not working in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786203/node-js-socket-io-app-not-working-in-iphone)

I should note I am just using the default SSL that heroku provides and want to try to avoid costs while this is just a fun project, but not totally opposed if it is the only option

Thanks!

Comment: This issue may be related to SocketIO, can you check the debug info of it?

Comment: Have you check the discussion [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2924) as well?

Comment: Sorry, is there a way to check the debug info? I am not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: active JS in IOS https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-javascript/safari-iphone-ipod